# Software to translate a Russian map to English

Tags: translation

I need a website that allows me to  type in Russian to English translate because I have the 1990 Russian map that was given to me a long time ago. I would like to look it up what it is and write it down.

What is a good program or online? The date on the map is 1990, so I don't know if the Russian alphabet change since the break-up of the Soviet Union.

I also would like to see if there is a website where can I look it up for the old maps that are online ?

Looks like the map was in the former Leingrad which is now is in St. Petersburg, Russia.

Comment: [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#ru/en/), [Yandex Translate](https://translate.yandex.com/?lang=ru-en), [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Moscow,+Russia/@55.7494733,37.3523199,10z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x46b54afc73d4b0c9:0x3d44d6cc5757cf4c), [Yandex Maps](https://maps.yandex.com/).

Comment: Curious  Is there a website that can I go to Russian maps online that you know of ?  I looked up the word from Russian to English . This map is from the former Leningrad and its a surrounding ? That is in St Petersburg . I will get that map to scan it and upload it to the online when I have the chance to do that.

Comment: Click on the 'on-line Maps' link that I cited above, type 'St.Petersburg' and the app will show you what you need. Both online-maps provide names of countries, cities, streets, in English and Russian.

Comment: I meant old maps not the current ones ?

Comment: You ask on-line service that lets you upload a scanned map of 1990, and what would this online service has translated all the text on the map for you?

Comment: It would be a part of historical maps that anyone can use it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use google translate to type Cyrillic symbols. Select Russian language as the one to translate from, and at the left-bottom corner, near Py button, use the dropdown menu to show Russian keyboard or hand-drawing box.

And no, Russian alphabet did not change since 1990. The latest change was in 1918 when they threw a couple of letters out.

Answer (score 2):

I would STRONGLY suggest that you look up the location that's on your map on google maps or yandex maps. Politically-neutral names didn't change that much since 1990. Names of geographic locations are often translated phonetically and not literally, so online services may produce misleading results. For example, 
***Китай-город*** metro station in Moscow should be translated to English as ***Kitaj-gorod*** and not as ***China town*** as google-translate suggests. There are plenty of similar examples.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you using an on-screen keyboard to type cyrillyc and a web site maps.yandex.ru (a russian search engine and map provider) 
I've tried out several old names (e.g. Свердловск - now Ekaterinburg, Ленинград - now St.Petersburg, площадь Калинина в Москве - now metro starion Teatralnaya) and looks like it works. 
Not sure if Google will work this way but Yandex is very Russian-oriented and may help.

Also, Russian wikipedia usually lists all the previous names for well known places, including years of change.

The good news is our alphabet didn't change since 1990, moreover since the 1920s.